# Run multiple Google Apps Script clasp commands in parallel using a Bash script

Tags: bash, google-apps-script, parallel-processing, background-process, clasp

I have several hundred Google Apps Script projects and have a variety of Bash scripts for managing the projects using the [clasp](https://github.com/google/clasp) tool (a Node.js app). Many of the scripts require using `clasp pull` to first pull the projects locally before taking some actions on the local files, so I have a script which loops through local clasp project folders and runs `clasp pull` on each. The loop iterates through directories sequentially so if it takes 3-4 seconds to pull a project, it ends up taking 5-6 minutes to run it per 100 projects.

My goal is to be able to run the `clasp pull` commands in parallel so that they all start at the same time, and to be able to know which projects were successfully pulled vs which projects failed to be pulled.

Given a directory structure like this:

```
├── project-1
│   ├── .clasp.json
│   ├── .claspignore
│   ├── _main.js
│   └── appsscript.json
├── project-2
│   ├── .clasp.json
│   ├── .claspignore
│   ├── _main.js
│   └── appsscript.json
├── project-3
│   ├── .clasp.json
│   ├── .claspignore
│   ├── _main.js
│   └── appsscript.json
└── pull_all.sh
```

And this `pull_all.sh` Bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# use Node 14.17.5 to prevent "Error: Looks like you are offline." errors
# (see https://github.com/google/clasp/issues/872)
[ -s "/usr/local/opt/nvm/nvm.sh" ] && . "/usr/local/opt/nvm/nvm.sh"
nvm install 14.17.5
nvm use 14.17.5

find . -name '.clasp.json' | 
while read file; do
    (
        cd "$(dirname "$file")"
        project_dir_name="$(basename "$(pwd)")"
        echo "Pulling project ($project_dir_name)"
        clasp pull
    ) &
done
```

When running this script it outputs the line for "Pulling project" for each directory, then gives a shell prompt, implying that the script has finished executing. But then  without the user doing anything, 3-4 seconds later it shows the output of all the `clasp pull` commands (apparently running in parallel because some of the output of the commands are out of order/overlapping), then hangs, and does not give a new shell prompt. At this point I have to press ctrl+c to terminate the script.

The complete output ends up looking like this:

```
$ ./pull_all.sh
v14.17.5 is already installed.
Now using node v14.17.5 (npm v6.14.14)
Now using node v14.17.5 (npm v6.14.14)
Pulling project (project-3)
Pulling project (project-2)
Pulling project (project-1)
$
Cloned 2 files.
⠙ Pulling files…└─ appsscript.json
└─ _main.js
Cloned 2 files.
└─ _main.js
└─ appsscript.json
Cloned 2 files.
└─ _main.js
```

To force one of the scripts to fail, I can change the `scriptId` to an invalid script ID in any of the `.clasp.json` files. In this case I do see the expected output of:

```
Could not find script.
Did you provide the correct scriptId?
Are you logged in to the correct account with the script?
```

... but it's still mixed in with the rest of the output and it's not clear which project that came from.

How can I make it so that:

1. The script does not cause a new shell prompt to appear during the execution of the script.
2. The script outputs a line indicating the success or failure of each `clasp pull` operation, referenced by the directory name of the project (where the `.clasp.json` file was found).
3. Bonus: suppress the output of `clasp pull` so the script only shows the success or failure result of each project (referenced by the directory name).

Note: I've mentioned `clasp pull` as an example command, but a valid solution would allow me to run any clasp command as a background process in a bash while loop, including, but not limited to `clasp push`, `clasp deploy`, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**I'd suggest the following solution:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# use Node 14.17.5 to prevent "Error: Looks like you are offline." errors
# (see https://github.com/google/clasp/issues/872)
[ -s "/usr/local/opt/nvm/nvm.sh" ] && . "/usr/local/opt/nvm/nvm.sh"
nvm install 14.17.5
nvm use 14.17.5

# Check and process command line
if (( $# < 1 )); then
    echo "Usage: $(basename "$0") ACTION [ARG]..."
    exit 2
fi
action="$1"
args=("${@:2}")

# Define cleanup handler, create temporary log directory
trap '[[ -n "$(jobs -p)" ]] && kill -- -$$; [[ -n "${logdir}" ]] && rm -rf "${logdir}"' EXIT
logdir=$(mktemp -d)

# Start specified action for each project
declare -A pid_pro_map=() pid_log_map=()
readarray -t files < <(find . -name '.clasp.json' -printf "%P\n" | sort -V)
for file in "${files[@]}"; do
    project=$(dirname "${file}")
    logfile=$(mktemp -p "${logdir}")
    ( cd "${project}" && clasp "${action}" "${args[@]}" ) &>"${logfile}" &
    pid=$!; pid_pro_map[${pid}]="${project}"; pid_log_map[${pid}]="${logfile}"
    echo -e "Started action '\e[1m${action}\e[0m' for project '\e[1m${project}\e[0m' (pid ${pid})"
done

# Wait for background jobs to finish and report results
echo -e "\nWaiting for background jobs to finish...\n"
jobs_done=0; jobs_total=${#files[@]}
while true; do
    wait -n -p pid; result=$?
    [[ -z "${pid}" ]] && break
    jobs_done=$((jobs_done + 1))
    if (( ${result} == 0 )); then
        echo -e "Action '\e[1m${action}\e[0m' for project '\e[1m${pid_pro_map[${pid}]}\e[0m' (pid ${pid}) (${jobs_done}/${jobs_total}): \e[1;32mSUCCESS\e[0m"
    else
        echo -e "Action '\e[1m${action}\e[0m' for project '\e[1m${pid_pro_map[${pid}]}\e[0m' (pid ${pid}) (${jobs_done}/${jobs_total}): \e[1;31mFAILURE\e[0m"
        cat "${pid_log_map[${pid}]}"
    fi
done
```

**Features:**

- Allows to run any action supported by `clasp` (e.g. `pull`, `push`, `deploy`)
- Performs the specified action for each project in parallel in the background
- Output produced by `clasp` is suppressed (but captured to be printed in case of failure)
- Waits for background tasks to finish and reports results as soon as they become available
- Provides information regarding success/failure for each project (including output produced by `clasp` for further analysis in case of failure)
- Displays current progress (in the form of `<projects-done>/<projects-total>`)
- Colored output for increased readability

**Requirements:**

- Bash >= 5.1 (details: Bash >= 5.1 for `wait -p`, Bash >= 4.3 for `wait -n`, Bash >= 4.0 for associative arrays)
- GNU find (part of *findutils*) for `find ... -printf "%P\n"`; Possible workaround:

  ```
  readarray -t files < <(find . -name '.clasp.json' | sort -V)
  for file in "${files[@]}"; do
      project=$(dirname "${file#'./'}")
  ```

**Sample output:**

[image: sample output]

---

In response to [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69653686/run-multiple-google-apps-script-clasp-commands-in-parallel-using-a-bash-script/69707491#comment123285501_69707491), here is a possible tweak to limit the amount of concurrent background jobs being spawned:

```
# Start specified action for each project
max_jobs=25; poll_delay="0.1s"
declare -A pid_pro_map=() pid_log_map=()
readarray -t files < <(find . -name '.clasp.json' -printf "%P\n" | sort -V)
for file in "${files[@]}"; do
    if (( ${max_jobs} > 0 )); then
        while jobs=$(jobs -r -p | wc -l) && (( ${jobs} >= ${max_jobs} )); do
            sleep "${poll_delay}"
        done
    fi
    project=$(dirname "${file}")
    logfile=$(mktemp -p "${logdir}")
    ( cd "${project}" && clasp "${action}" "${args[@]}" ) &>"${logfile}" &
    pid=$!; pid_pro_map[${pid}]="${project}"; pid_log_map[${pid}]="${logfile}"
    echo -e "Started action '\e[1m${action}\e[0m' for project '\e[1m${project}\e[0m' (pid ${pid})"
done
```

Additionally, this could be employed to cut the amount of background processes being spawned in half:

```
( cd "${project}" && exec clasp "${action}" "${args[@]}" ) &>"${logfile}" &
```

This will replace the subshell's process with `clasp`, which should be perfectly fine as the subshell looses its usefulness right after executing `cd` anyway.

Comment: After testing all proposed solutions I've found this one to be the most feature-complete and easiest to integrate into my workflow, and I've marked it as accepted. However, additional modifications were required for my use case (which I consider to be out-of-scope for my question): When testing the script against 100 projects, on average about 7% of the clasp commands would fail for various reasons. Spawning 100 node processes at once is heavily dependent on the host machine's CPU and if it can't handle the load it will lead to unpredictable results and random errors...

Comment: ... In my case a workaround was to add a `sleep 1.5` after each clasp command to spread out the load. I'd experimented with different sleep durations and found 1.5s to be the shortest amount of time where I wouldn't observe any errors during repeated testing. Without the sleep (but with the 7% avg. error rate) the script was 3.9x faster than my original solution, but even with the sleep it's still 1.7x faster. This is a significant improvement for me but in the future I may update the script to loop through any failed clasp actions and automatically re-try them until they succeed.

Comment: Also, note that if you're running this on macOS, you may need to use homebrew to install `bash` (11.6 Big Sur ships with Bash 3.2.57 but bash 4+ is required for associative arrays) and `findutils` (includes GNU find, which is required for the find args), and also add findutils to your path by adding this to your `.zshrc`: `export PATH=/usr/local/opt/findutils/libexec/gnubin:$PATH`

Comment: @Employee: thank you very much, especially for your feedback. Regarding `macOS`, I knew about that and had scanned the question for any mention of it, but since there was none I figured it's out of scope. Only Apple knows why they ship an ancient version of Bash... As for the *overload* scenario you've described, I actually have a quick fix for that if you're interested. I'll add it below my original answer.

Comment: @Employee: I added the possible overload fix and the requirements you mentioned (Bash, findutils) to the answer.

Comment: These are great improvements, thank you! I've confirmed that the updated `find` command and use of parameter expansion to remove the `./` from the paths eliminates the need for GNU find/`findutils`. As for the performance optimization, the update does indeed limit the number of concurrent background node processes, and it's more effective than my fixed sleep value approach. I've built a test harness and have been testing for ~6hrs, and I will post my findings later today or this weekend.

Comment: @Employee: Looking forward to the results of your tests. I added one last possible performance tweak that should cut the amount of background processes in half (see end of answer).

Comment: What is `wait -n -p pid`? How does `$pid` change in the last loop?

Comment: @dan: `wait -n -p pid` waits until *one* of the background jobs finishes, then returns the job's pid in `pid` and the job's exit code as `$?`. When there are no jobs to wait for, `wait` returns with `pid` being empty (last iteration of loop). For details, check out `help wait` and/or `man bash`.

Comment: @Maxxim Oh, apparently this is quite a new feature. From `bash-5.1.8/NEWS` > “features added to bash-5.1 since the release of bash-5.0” > “q. wait: has a new -p VARNAME option, which stores the PID returned by `wait -n`“. I'm on `5.0` and was getting `invalid option`. You should probably change required `bash` version to `5.1`.

Comment: @dan: This explains a lot, thank you. While developing my answer, I felt like 'Why haven't I used this before?'. Now I know why. Even `wait -n` was only introduced with `Bash 4.3`. I added the information to my answer. Great find.

Comment: Following up on my testing: It's been difficult to test this because while experimenting with adjusting the max number of jobs, the average error rates fluctuate quite a bit, even though I'd been careful to maintain a consistent test environment (no other apps/processes running, limited background network activity, etc). Ultimately I'd found that the max number concurrent jobs my machine can handle with a 0% avg. error rate is 3, which results in a 3x improvement over my original solution. However, when testing with the max jobs set between 4-100, the avg. error rate only goes up to ~4-14%...

Comment: So when dealing with 100 projects, there's never more than like ~15 or so projects which would error out. My end goal is to have this script be portable and have other team members with varying hardware run it without having to determine/set `max_jobs` themselves. So initially I thought to build some kind of benchmarking test into the script to determine the optimal `max_jobs` value, but ultimately that would add too much additional time to the script and would defeat the purpose of parallel processing...

Comment: Having a pre-requisite benchmarking script could work, but that's an extra thing someone would have to do and seems excessive for a relatively simple operation. So I think the best solution in this case would be to set a default value for `max_jobs` (25 or so) and then have the script keep track of which jobs failed, and then automatically re-try each until 100% of the jobs have succeeded. Not sure if the script should be modified so that the original loop handles re-trying failed jobs until they've all succeeded (ideal), or so that failed jobs are added to a separate array...

Comment: ... which is handled afterwards (not the most efficient but could probably still work). @Maxxim Would you be interested in implementing this modification? Happy to discuss if you need any clarification. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> 1. The script does not cause a new shell prompt to appear during the execution of the script.

The new shell prompt is occurring because you are creating a new subshell in the `while` loop (for further guidance on how subshells work in bash, reference this page from tldp.org: [link](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/subshells.html)). To prevent this from occurring, call the command directly without placing them within parentheses.

> 2. The script outputs a line indicating the success or failure of each clasp pull operation, referenced by the directory name of the project
>    (where the .clasp.json file was found).

You can generally catch if a command fails by adding an `||` after the command (e.g. `grep "foobar" file.txt || echo "Error: 'foobar' not found in file.txt"`). You could also put the command in an `if`/`else` and echo the appropriate status message for each.

> 3. Bonus: suppress the output of clasp pull so the script only shows the
>    success or failure result of each project (referenced by the directory
>    name).

**Note:** This response uses the aforementioned solution from the second question.
You could create 2 arrays—1 for success and 1 for failures, and then inside of the if/else statements, add the current iteration element to the correct array.

Feel free to ask for clarification if any part of the above was not clear!

Comment: The shell prompt is appearing because the script has actually exited, not because of the parenthesis subshell (they won’t cause that).

Answer (score 1):

You should enforce script to wait for output before finish:

```
{ 
    while IFS= read -d $'\0' -ru $find file; do
        (
            cd "$(dirname "$file")"
            project_dir_name="$(basename "$(pwd)")"
            echo "Pulling project ($project_dir_name)"
            if clasp pull </dev/null 2>&1 ;then
                printf '\nExeClaspResult: %s Success\n' "$project_dir_name"
            else
                printf '\nExeClaspResult: %s Failed\n' "$project_dir_name"
            fi
        ) &
    done {find}< <(find . -name '.clasp.json' -print0)
    wait
} |
    sed -une 's/^ExeClaspResult: //p'
```

Where:

1. No interaction
2. All ouptut wll be dropped (by `sed`)
3. Only result will be shown.

If you wanna do some *debugging*:

```
{ 
    while IFS= read -d $'\0' -ru $find file; do
        (
            cd "$(dirname "$file")"
            project_dir_name="$(basename "$(pwd)")"
            echo "Pulling project ($project_dir_name)"
            if clasp pull </dev/null > >(
                  sed "s/^/OUT $project_dir_name: /") 2> >(
                  sed "s/^/ERR $project_dir_name: /"
                );then
                printf '\nExeClaspResult: %s Success\n' "$project_dir_name"
            else
                printf '\nExeClaspResult: %s Failed\n' "$project_dir_name"
            fi
        ) &
    done {find}< <(find . -name '.clasp.json' -print0)
    wait
} |
    sed -ue '
        s/^ExeClaspResult: \(.* Failed\)$/\o33[31m** \1 **\o33[0m/;
        s/^ExeClaspResult: \(.*\)$/\o33[32m** \1 **\o33[0m/;'
```

Will show all output prefixed by `OUT $project` or `ERR project`, and color results in green if success or red when failed.

Answer (score 1):

My approach would be to log all the asynchronous invocations first. These will happen quickly. Then start printing the task failed/succeeded log.

This script uses named pipes to achieve this. Asynchronous commands happen in subshells, which inherit open file descriptors that the success/fail messages can print too. We can wait until all the invocations are logged, before sending these to the terminal.

Output of `pull all` is hidden. It can be replaced with another command or shell function.

`stdout` and `stderr` can be redirected as normal (like `pull-all 2>err-log`, or `pull-all >/dev/null` to see errors only).

The script waits for the pull commands to complete, then exits normally.

If it's interrupted (ctrl+c), all child processes are killed. Otherwise they would keep running after the script exits. I'm not sure if there's a better way to handle that or not.

**Solution:**

```
#!/bin/bash

cleanup () {
    exec 3>&-
    exec 4>&-

    rm .pull-all-log.fifo .pull-all-log-err.fifo

    kill $(jobs -p)
    kill -9 $(jobs -p) &>/dev/null
}

# use Node 14.17.5 to prevent "Error: Looks like you are offline." errors
# (see https://github.com/google/clasp/issues/872)
[[ -s "/usr/local/opt/nvm/nvm.sh" ]] && . "/usr/local/opt/nvm/nvm.sh"
nvm install 14.17.5
nvm use 14.17.5

# you can use /tmp or mktemp -u if you're worried about clobbering
rm -f .pull-all-log.fifo .pull-all-log-err.fifo
mkfifo .pull-all-log.fifo .pull-all-log-err.fifo
trap cleanup EXIT

exec 3<> .pull-all-log.fifo
exec 4<> .pull-all-log-err.fifo

for file in ./*/.clasp.json; do
    [[ -d "$file" ]] && continue

    parent=$(dirname "$file")
    proj=${parent##*/}

    echo "Pulling $proj..."

    {
        cd "$parent"

        if clasp pull &>/dev/null; then
            echo "Pulling $proj succeeded" >&3
        else
            echo "Pulling $proj FAILED" >&4
        fi
    } &
done

running_pids=$(jobs -p)

cat <&3 &
cat <&4 >&2 &

[[ "$running_pids" ]] && wait $running_pids
```

**Example output:**

```
Pulling project-1...
Pulling project-2...
Pulling project-3...
Pulling project-4...
Pulling project-5...
Pulling project-6...
Pulling project-7...
Pulling project-8...
Pulling project-9...
Pulling project-1 succeeded
Pulling project-9 succeeded
Pulling project-3 succeeded
Pulling project-4 FAILED
Pulling project-5 succeeded
Pulling project-2 succeeded
Pulling project-6 FAILED
Pulling project-7 FAILED
Pulling project-8 FAILED
```

`FAILED` or `succeeded` are printed for every invocation, whenever it finishes (even if it's before the invocation loop ends).

The example directories are named `project-1` etc. I recreated your example tree to test it.

Answer (score 0):

Can you do:

```
parallel -j100 --tag 'cd {//} && clasp pull || echo Fail' ::: */.clasp.json
```

If you only want output from `clasp` if it fails:

```
parallel -j100 --tag 'cd {//} && neno clasp pull || echo Fail' ::: */.clasp.json
```

`neno` is https://gitlab.com/ole.tange/tangetools/-/tree/master/neno